# Get values from model in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm starting with ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have one question.

I've this code to add data to properties in Model.

```
    public void SetModelValues()
    {
        var modelObj = new MyModel();
        modelObj.name="MyName";
        modelObj.email="someone@mymail.com";
        modelObj.company="MyCompany";
        modelObj.message="Some text here";
    }
```

How I do to get, from another action, this values?

Thanks and sorry for "newbism" :)

Comment: Its not clear what you exactly want. What do you mean by "How I do to get, from another action, this values?" You want these values to be sent to another action?

Comment: Please clarify your question and perhaps include examples of what you think the 2 action methods you are referring to should look like.

Comment: You need to `post the data to another action`. Render the model to a view, from the view post the rendered data using regular `form post` or `Ajax Post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method, as is, would not set any values for your Model. You need to setup your Model and then pass it to your View.

For example, your controller would be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var modelObj = new MyModel();
    modelObj.name="MyName";
    modelObj.email="someone@mymail.com";
    modelObj.company="MyCompany";
    modelObj.message="Some text here";

    return View(modelObj);
}
```

Once you do that, the model will be available for use within your View.

Corresponding Razor view `Index.cshtml` can be something like this:

```
@model MyModel

<p>Name: @Model.name</p>
<p>Email: @Model.email</p>
<p>Company: @Model.company</p>
<p>Message: @Model.message</p>
```

HTH

Comment: this answer only tells how to use model data in the view, and not how to get it "back" in the controller, which is what was asked.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to help complete Nasir's answer. What he outlined is perfectly true. But to answer your quest as how to access those values from another action, that view model must be passed back to that controller on the next postback. So for instance, You create and hydrate the view model in one action which get's passed to the view. MVC passes data back to the form on the next postback by creating controls with your values. If you use the values in the view model, they are lost, so either render a control with those values:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty);
```

Or if you want to make sure it is passed on the next postback but don't have a use for it being displayed, the just create the hidden field so that it is still rendered in the source so that it can be passed back to the next action:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyProperty);
```

So what happens is when you post this form back, it will be sent as form data (key value pairs) back to the controller action that is called by submitting the form. MVC will attempt to deserialize this into one of the Action argument types (so make sure one of them is the same type as your ViewModel). By doing this, the information will be available in that action.

**To Elaborate a bit more**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

// Index.cshtml - bound to MyViewModel
// This will render a text box that will read "Property 1". It will also render a hidden field 
// containing "Property 2" but will not be displayed on the page. When you click the submit button, 
// it will post back to the PostTest action on the Home controller. Notice that Prop3 wasn't used
// so it won't be included in the postback
@model MyProject.Models.MyViewModel
<div>
    @using(Html.BeginForm("PostTest", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Prop1);  
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Prop2);

        <button type="submit">GO!</button>
    }
</div>

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // your index view is bound to MyViewModel so we'll hydrate that and send it to the view for rendering
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        viewModel.Prop1 = "Property 1";
        viewModel.Prop2 = "Property 2";
        viewModel.Prop3 = "Property 3";

        return View(vm);
    }

    public ActionResult PostTest(MyViewModel vm) // mvc will attempt to deserialize your form data into this object
    {
        var testProp1 = vm.Prop1; // "Property 1"
        var testProp2 = vm.Prop2; // "Property 2"
        var testProp3 = vm.Prop3; // null
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it actually answer the question. The currently accepted answer just tells how to use model data in the view, and not how to get it "back" in the controller.